# Let $f(z)=e^x+ie^{2y}$. For what values of $z\in\mathbb{C}$ does $f'(z)$ exist?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let us define the function $f:\mathbb{C}\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$ by
$$f(z)=e^x+ie^{2y}$$
where $z=x+iy$ for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.

**Question:** For what values of $z\in\mathbb{C}$ does $f'(z)$ exist?

**Attempt:** If $f'(z)$ exists at some point $z\in\mathbb{C}$, then $f$ must satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations at that point. Namely,
$$u_x=e^x=v_y=2e^y$$
$$u_y=0=-v_x=0$$
Thus, we must have $e^x=2 e^{2y}$ or $x=\ln 2+2y$, so $z$ is on the line
$$z=(\ln 2+2t)+it,\quad t\in\mathbb{R}$$
However, this line is *not* an open set, so this condition is not sufficient. What can we do then? With this condition we find
\begin{align} \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h} &=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^{x+h_1}+ie^{2(y+h_2)}-e^x-ie^{2y}}{h_1+ih_2}\\
&=e^{2y}\lim_{h\to0}\frac{2(e^{h_1}-1)+i(e^{2h_2}-1)}{h_1+ih_2}\\
\end{align}
**Does this limit exists? How do we know?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact the the line is not an open set is irrelevant. For a function $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, a sufficient condition for the existence of $f'(z)$ at the point $z_0=x_0+iy_0$ is that the first-order partial derivatives $u_x,u_y,v_x,v_y$ exist throughout a neighborhood of $(x_0,y_0)$ and are continuous at $(x_0,y_0)$, and satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations at $(x_0,y_0)$.

In your example, inasmuch as the functions $u(x,y)=e^x$ and $v(x,y)=e^{2y}$ are continuously differentiable everywhere, the **derivative $f'(z)$ exists** at every point where the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied. Of course $f(z)$ is **not analytic** at any point, because that line has no interior points. (A function $f(z)$ is **analytic** at a point if it's **differentiable** throughout some **neighborhood** of the point.)